# StringTemplate - How to iterate through list inside list?

Tags: java, list, stringtemplate

Let's say i've list of objects that i want to iterate in stringTemplate. the object look like that:

public class a1 {

```
private String name;
private String value;
private List<a2> a2list;
 public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
 public List<a2> geta2list() {
    return a2;
}
```

}

public class a2 {

```
private String name;
private String value;
 public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

imagine something like a conversation. a1 is the creator and a2 is answers.
i did that:

```
$a1:{

    <div>$it.value$</div>
   $a2:{

      <div>$it.name$</div>
      <div>$it.value$</div>
      }$

}$
```

and i'm getting "action parse error;"

any ideas?

Thanks!
Koby

Comment: Please let me know if what you had asked had worked. I am trying to so a similar task, and not able to iterate through a List within a List. Please Help !!!

Answer (score 1):

What's the syntax error?  Perhaps you need <...> not $...$